# Obtain most recent value for based on index in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

On every meeting date, new gdp growth forecasts are made 3 to 4 years into the future. If the gdp growth forecast for a `forecast_year` is similar to what it was in the last `meeting_date`, it does not get a new entry in the table.

Is there an easy way to add these missing `forecast_year` entries for all `meeting_dates`, quoting the most recent `gdp_growth(%)` figures available as of the latest `meeting_date`?

To clarify, here is the input table `df_in`:

| meeting_date | forecast_year | gdp_growth (%) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2007-11-20 | 2007 | 2.45 |
| 2007-11-20 | 2008 | 2.15 |
| 2007-11-20 | 2009 | 2.50 |
| 2007-11-20 | 2010 | 2.55 |
| 2008-02-20 | 2008 | 1.65 |
| 2008-02-20 | 2009 | 2.40 |
| 2008-02-20 | 2010 | 2.75 |
| 2008-05-21 | 2008 | 0.75 |
| 2008-05-21 | 2010 | 2.85 |
| 2008-07-16 | 2008 | 1.30 |
| 2008-07-16 | 2010 | 2.75 |
| 2008-11-19 | 2008 | 0.15 |
| 2008-11-19 | 2009 | 0.45 |
| 2008-11-19 | 2011 | 3.20 |

Here is the shape of the output table I need to output, `df_out`. Rows that need to be added are in bold. What pandas manipulations are needed to transform `df_in` into `df_out`?

| meeting_date | forecast_year | GPD Growth (%) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2007-11-20 | 2007 | 2.45 |
| 2007-11-20 | 2008 | 2.15 |
| 2007-11-20 | 2009 | 2.50 |
| 2007-11-20 | 2010 | 2.55 |
| 2008-02-20 | 2008 | 1.65 |
| 2008-02-20 | 2009 | 2.40 |
| 2008-02-20 | 2010 | 2.75 |
| 2008-05-21 | 2008 | 0.75 |
| **2008-05-21** | **2009** | **2.40** |
| 2008-05-21 | 2010 | 2.85 |
| 2008-07-16 | 2008 | 1.30 |
| **2008-07-16** | **2009** | **2.40** |
| 2008-07-16 | 2010 | 2.75 |
| 2008-11-19 | 2008 | 0.15 |
| 2008-11-19 | 2009 | 0.45 |
| **2008-11-19** | **2010** | **2.75** |
| 2008-11-19 | 2011 | 3.20 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way via `pivot`:

```
k = df1.pivot(*df1).ffill().stack().reset_index(name = 'GPD Growth (%)')
df = k[~(pd.to_datetime(k["meeting_date"]).dt.year.gt(k["forecast_year"]))]
```

OUTPUT:

```
   meeting_date  forecast_year  GPD Growth (%)
0    2007-11-20           2007            2.45
1    2007-11-20           2008            2.15
2    2007-11-20           2009            2.50
3    2007-11-20           2010            2.55
5    2008-02-20           2008            1.65
6    2008-02-20           2009            2.40
7    2008-02-20           2010            2.75
9    2008-05-21           2008            0.75
10   2008-05-21           2009            2.40
11   2008-05-21           2010            2.85
13   2008-07-16           2008            1.30
14   2008-07-16           2009            2.40
15   2008-07-16           2010            2.75
17   2008-11-19           2008            0.15
18   2008-11-19           2009            0.45
19   2008-11-19           2010            2.75
20   2008-11-19           2011            3.20
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
x = (
    df.set_index(["meeting_date", "forecast_year"])
    .unstack(level=1)
    .ffill()
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
)
# remove rows where meeting_date > forecast_year
x = x[~(pd.to_datetime(x["meeting_date"]).dt.year > x["forecast_year"])]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   meeting_date  forecast_year  gdp_growth (%)
0    2007-11-20           2007            2.45
1    2007-11-20           2008            2.15
2    2007-11-20           2009            2.50
3    2007-11-20           2010            2.55
5    2008-02-20           2008            1.65
6    2008-02-20           2009            2.40
7    2008-02-20           2010            2.75
9    2008-05-21           2008            0.75
10   2008-05-21           2009            2.40
11   2008-05-21           2010            2.85
13   2008-07-16           2008            1.30
14   2008-07-16           2009            2.40
15   2008-07-16           2010            2.75
17   2008-11-19           2008            0.15
18   2008-11-19           2009            0.45
19   2008-11-19           2010            2.75
20   2008-11-19           2011            3.20
```

EDIT: Removed `MultiIndex.from_product` - not needed